# Cannot clone repo: "fatal: remote did not send all necessary objects"

Tags: git

I am trying to clone this repo: https://github.com/emonney/QuickApp but I get error:

> fatal: remote did not send all necessary objects

This is full output:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/emonney/QuickApp
Cloning into 'QuickApp'...
remote: Counting objects: 2150, done.
remote: Total 2150 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 2150
Receiving objects: 100% (2150/2150), 30.28 MiB | 3.01 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (1471/1471), done.
usage: git rev-list [OPTION] <commit-id>... [ -- paths... ]
  limiting output:
    --max-count=<n>
    --max-age=<epoch>
    --min-age=<epoch>
    --sparse
    --no-merges
    --min-parents=<n>
    --no-min-parents
    --max-parents=<n>
    --no-max-parents
    --remove-empty
    --all
    --branches
    --tags
    --remotes
    --stdin
    --quiet
  ordering output:
    --topo-order
    --date-order
    --reverse
  formatting output:
    --parents
    --children
    --objects | --objects-edge
    --unpacked
    --header | --pretty
    --abbrev=<n> | --no-abbrev
    --abbrev-commit
    --left-right
    --count
  special purpose:
    --bisect
    --bisect-vars
    --bisect-all
fatal: remote did not send all necessary objects
Unlink of file 'QuickApp/.git/objects/pack/pack-43a2031dca4d230e6f6a3333445136c9a7928657.idx' failed. Should I try again? (y/n)
```

If I select `y` it just keeps giving me the same error.

Is this a problem with the repo or something I can fix?  (I don't own repo, just trying to get the code)

Comment: Looks like it was/is a bug in 2.17.1.windows.1, with `git clone` passing the wrong arguments to `git rev-list` when attempting to index the pack file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works fine for me.  Most likely your `git` is either very old (I'm using 2.15), or your filesystem is obsolete or otherwise inadequate to the task (e.g. are you using FAT?).

Try it on another system, or upgrade your `git` if it is old.

Comment: My git version is `git version 2.17.1.windows.1` and I am using NTFS (Windows 10).  So I think everything is up to date.

Comment: Interesting.  Please try on another system.

Comment: I updated to 2.18 and it worked.  Strange thing is I can download other repos fine, it was just this one causing issue

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem, and a simple reinstall solved it for me. Since I'm on Debian 9.7.0, it was:

`sudo apt install --reinstall git`

Most package managers don't delete your settings/configs so it doesn't hurt to try this before further troubleshooting. If it doesn't work then well, you only wasted the amount of time it took to type out the command.